# Chart.js positive/negative values fill with out twist

Tags: chart.js

Used the last 2 hours trying to figure out how to avoid the wird twist that happens when using fill with chart.js 3when alternating between positive and negative values.

This is with out fill

[image: With out fill]

Current out puut with fill

[image: Current]

Wanted behaviour (This is the way i want to present the data and the fill way i can't figure out how to do, can any one point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `fill` as `true` which is equivalent to `origin` for backwards compatibility. This mode fills to the zero line.

To get the behaviour you want you need to change from `fill: true` to `fill: 'start'`.

Here in the documentation you can see how all the different filling modes affect the chart: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/area/line-boundaries.html